# async json loading with Swift - long loading time problem

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous

I'm working on a map app and I have a geojson file with a few hundred thousand items in it. I can load and show the data, can see the pins on the map, the custom annotations and the clustering all works. I'm not happy with the way I load the file though.

I have two versions:

```
private var thingsOnMap: [MyDataClass] = []

private func loadInitialData() {

    guard let fileName = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myGeojsonFile", withExtension: "geojson"),
        let myData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileName)
    else {
        return
    } do {
        let features = try MKGeoJSONDecoder()
            .decode(myData)
            .compactMap { $0 as? MKGeoJSONFeature }
        let allData = features.compactMap(MyDataClass.init)
        thingsOnMap.append(contentsOf: allData)
    } catch {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
}
```

then I just call this method. This works, I can see the pins within a few seconds, but it feels like a really wrong way to do it this way.

The second version looks like this:

```
private func loadInitialData(completion: @escaping (_ data: [MyDataClass]?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {                
    var receivedError: Error?
    
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        guard let fileName = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myGeojsonFile", withExtension: "geojson"),
            let myData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileName)
        else {
            return
        } do {
            let features = try MKGeoJSONDecoder()
                .decode(myData)
                .compactMap { $0 as? MKGeoJSONFeature }
            let allData = features.compactMap(MyDataClass.init)
            self.thingsOnMap.append(contentsOf: allData)
        } catch {
            receivedError = error
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(self.thingsOnMap, receivedError)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call it this way:

```
    loadInitialData { (data, error) in
        if data != nil {
            self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.thingsOnMap)
        }
    }
```

This works nicely and it feels safer, but it takes roughly 35-40 seconds to see the data on the map. Why is that huge difference between the loading times? I see map apps all the time with lots of items (like car charging stations across Europe - hundreds of thousands items) loading in basically instantly. How can I achieve that? Or at least, is there a way to make it at least a bit faster?

Comment: You are running your second version on the global queue with a very low priority, what about trying a higher one like [userInitiated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/qosclass/userinitiated) instead?

Comment: yeah, I changed it to userInteractive and it loads in 3-4 secs, thanks! totally forgot to test it with different setings... Thank you!